# how to get seller id and product id in flutter firebase in one field for example, product field

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('products')
    .add({
  // how to add product id and seller id
  'image': imageUrls,
  'name': name,
  'category': category,
  'description': description,
  'price': 'RM' + ' ' + price,
  'weight': weight + 'gram',
  'stock': stock,
}).then((value) {
```

i don't know how to declare the difference seller when seller add their product to the seller homepage at my stream builder. also, the declaration of seller id and product id at the below mapping add data to firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can genrate a new random productID and for sellerID u can use userID of seller who adds the product.

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection('products');
String docID = collectionReference.doc().id;

collectionReference.doc(docID).set({
'productID': docID,
'sellerID': firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid, //(it is the userID of the seller who is adding this product)
'image': imageUrls,
'name': name,
'category': category,
'description': description,
'price': 'RM' + ' ' + price,
'weight': weight + 'gram',
'stock': stock,
}).then((value) { 
 // write your other logic here
});
```

Comment: how to declare the random productID and how to declare the sellerID who is adding that product . i just basic in flutter my bad :( if you can help me then i will thanks you a lot this is my final year project :(

Comment: @peanut Here is my updated answer that you can try now.